# Is it possible to bound the fraction of n-tosses that have exactly m-heads by one over m cube?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality

For positive integers $n$ and $m$, let us define 
$$ A_{m,n} := \frac{\binom{n}{m}}{2^n}.$$

Does there exist a constant $C$ independent of n, such that 
$$ A_{m,n} \leq \frac{C}{m^3} $$
for all $n$ and $m$?

Note that $A_{m,n} \leq 1$.

Remark: Instead of $\frac{1}{m^3}$, if it can be $\frac{1}{m^{2+r}}$ for some 
positive $r$, that is also fine. I need a sequence, such that after multiplying it by $m$, it should be summable (m=1 to infinity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such constant. The [*Central Binomial Coefficient*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) $\binom{2m}{m}$ is "too large." We have that
$$\frac{\binom{2m}{m}}{2^{2m}}$$ is of approximate size $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi m}}$.

Or else more simply  note that $\binom{2m}{m}\ge \binom{2m}{i}$ for all $i$, and that the sum of the $2m+1$ terms $\binom{2m}{i}$ is equal to $2^{2m}$. It follows that 
$$\frac{\binom{2m}{m}}{2^{2m}}\ge \frac{1}{2m+1}.$$